# Application.LoadPackage running slowly against older framework package

Tags: c#, ssis

We have a C# console app that is loading an SSIS package. When the package is targeted at SQL Server 2017 the package loads quickly. However, when the package is targeted at SQL Server 2014 (the version we need) its loading very slowly. Judging from the Visual Studio Output Window, I suspect the framework differences are causing problems. The Console app is using .Net Framework 4.5 while the package Script Tasks are using .Net Framework 4.0.

```
 Package newPackage = app.LoadPackage(originalPackageFullname, null);
```

Below are snippets from the Output window. The first is when I ran the console app against the SQL Server 2017 SSIS package and the second is when I ran the console app against the SQL Server 2014 SSIS package. The first shows some issues with the script tasks but the package is loaded quickly and appears to be correct when deployed. The second shows some Exceptions in mscorlib and Microsoft.Build.dll and a NullReferenceException on a script task. Also these issues are repeated on each of the four script tasks. Again, the package is eventually loaded successfully, but it in this case the load is painfully slow.

How can I speed up LoadPackage when loading a SQL Server 2014-targeted SSIS package from C# Console app using .Net 4.5 framework?

**Output when loading SQL Server 2017-targeted package:** There appear to be some issues but everything is loaded quickly and correctly

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll

**Output when loading SQL Server 2014-targeted package:** This same output is repeated four times for each of the script tasks in the SSIS package. Also it runs super slow. However, the load does eventually work

> Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in Microsoft.Build.dll
>   The thread 'In-proc Node (Default)' (0x705c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll

Comment: Am unable to replicate the slowness with an example package on my end..is it possible to share your package?

Comment: I can, but not publicly. Can I send it to you privately?

Comment: esskay.twea@gmail.com

Comment: It will have to wait until i'm back at work in about 9 hours. Thanks!

Comment: @SamKolli: Package sent to your email.

Comment: Ever figure out what was going on here? I have a similar situation.